# Does python provide a hook to customize json stringification based on key name?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to write an efficient stringification routine for logging dicts, but want to redact certain values based on key names.  I see that `JSONDecoder` provides the `object_pairs_hook` which provides key and value, but I don't see a corresponding hook for `JSONEncoder` - just 'default' which only provides value.  In my case, the values are just other strings so can't base the processing on that alone.  Is there something I missed?

For example, if I have a dict with:

```
{
   "username": "Todd",
   "role": "Editor",
   "privateKey": "1234ad1234e434134"
}
```

I would want to log:

```
'{"username":"Todd","role":"Editor","privateKey":"**redacted**"}'
```

Any good tools in python to do this? Or should I just recursively iterate the (possibly nested) dict directly?

Comment: (Thanks for the edit WaveShaper)

Comment: Use `json.dumps(<your-json-variable>)`.

Comment: @Rabindra: You seem to have missed the point of the question.

Comment: Oh, I noticed that now. Sorry, my answer/comment is not the correct one, then. Please ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *"reload"* it using the object hook then dump it again.

```
def redact(o):
    if 'privateKey' in o:
        o['privateKey'] = '***redacted***'
    return o
 
>>> d
{'username': 'Todd', 'role': 'Editor', 'privateKey': '1234ad1234e434134', 'foo': ['bar', {'privateKey': 'baz'}]}

>>> json.dumps(json.loads(json.dumps(d), object_hook=redact))
'{"username": "Todd", "role": "Editor", "privateKey": "***redacted***", "foo": ["bar", {"privateKey": "***redacted***"}]}'
```

Comment: Interesting - this does seem like the simplest solution.  It's about 4 times slower than my hack Im currently using (gets the job done but only if input structure doesn't change), but a much better general solution and about the same performance as the ugly function I wrote to iterate over the object and stringify as I went. Will probably mark as the solution, but going to give it a day. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to go with this solution = it involves the least re-implementation. And since I'm only cleaning up strings to go to log files, it's a tiny bit faster to just use 'str' instead of that final (by order of operation) json.dumps

Answer (score -1):

JSON library has two functions viz. `dumps()` and `loads()`. To convert a json to a string use `dumps()` and vice-versa use `loads()`.

```
import json
your_dict = {
   "username": "Todd",
   "role": "Editor",
   "privateKey": "1234ad1234e434134"
   }
string_of_your_json = json.dumps(your_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to just dump my dict - I want to dump all of it except the value of a particular key, so I need some kind of hook that tells me when that key is being processed

Comment: Sorry, I realized it that now. My answer/comment is not the correct one, then. Please ignore. However, I have a question. Do you just want to stringify it while also redacting the keys and passwords or you would also want to unstringify it while also retrieving the redacted keys/passwords whenever you need it?

Comment: This is for a log file, so I just want to stringify, never unstringify.